# Druid deletes column with all rows empty, how to make Druid keep these empty columns?

Tags: druid

Druid deletes column which all rows empty.

For example, have a table as below:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data |  |  |
| Data |  |  |
| Data | Data |  |

Then use HDFS index ingest CSV from HDFS to Druid. Column A and column B load succeeded. But column C not shown in Druid. Seems like Druid delete column C due to column C is empty with all rows.

So, I want to understand how to make Druid keep these empty columns.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?